# React Native Expo SDK 50.0.0 Error: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified

Tags: react-native, build, expo, android-14

When i build the apk of mi app in **expo (React-Native)** and i install in a device with **android 14 (SDK 34)**, the splash screen is shown, but them, the app closes with this error:

**Error: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts**

PD: The same apk in android 13 works correctly.

PDD: When you debug de app in the **expo app** in a real device with android 14 the app works correctly, but when you build and install the apk, dont work, happens the error descripted.

I have tried to modify some settings in app.config.js, but it isn´t possible to get solution to the error.

My code is (app.config.js):

```
export default {
  "expo": {
    "name": "ChidApp",
    "slug": "ChidApp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "sdkVersion": "50.0.0",
    "androidNavigationBar": {"backgroundColor": "#2d2d2d"},
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#232323"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.chidapp.app", 
      "receiver": {
        "intent": "com.chidapp.app.CUSTOM_INTENT",
        "exported": true
      },
      "versionCode": 1, 
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#232323"
      },
    },
    
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
  },
}
```